# Tableau take user input to change data and dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a way to have a dashboard where a user can input data and have it dynamically change the dashboard.

For example if i had a pie chart with 4 people each owning 25 percent space. If a user were to click on this chart. A prompt should pop up and they can enter user input, in this case their name. Once they input a function will run that is sitting on a server and the pie chart will change to having 5 people each owning 20 percent space.

Is this achievable in tableau through some api call or any other way. Any references or tutorials for starting points would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into dashboard extensions for this type of customization. You must be on version 2018.2 or later for these.

[Starting point](https://www.tableau.com/developer/extensions#reveal)

[3rd Party Extensions](https://extensiongallery.tableau.com/)